# Adding a setuptools command using `entry_points`

Tags: python, setuptools

Is it possible to add custom `setuptools` commands to a project by using the `entry_points` argument to the `setup()` call?

For example, I've added this to the `setup()` call of a project:

```
entry_points = {
    'distutils.commands': [
        'abc = sphinx.setup_command:BuildDoc',
    ],
},
```

But I still get no `abc` command when I do `python setup.py --help-commands`. Any ideas?

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#adding-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to add a `setuptools` command to be run via `$ python ./setup.py abc` I have had success with the following.

```
import sphinx.setup_command

setup(
  ...

  cmdclass={
      'abc': sphinx.setup_command.BuildDoc
  }, ...
)
```

See [extending distutils here.](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/extending.html)

Comment: So what's the use of `entry_points` then? For users of the project?

Comment: Apart from anything else, it allows you to install scripts that the users can use.